# Vba Web Scraping From Single Page Web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vba, web-scraping, single-page-application

Hi All can anyone help me
I have to put some value in InputBox and then click on Search button. According to that InputBox value data is shown in same page without changing its URL.
I made a code which puts a value in inputbox but when the code clicks on search button then pop-up is shown that the inputbox is empty

Inspect element For InputBox

```
<input id="u_edi_claim_key0" placeholder="" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }" name="u_edi_claim_key0" type="text" class="form-control input-sm ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-empty" ng-model="searchController.Obj[tab.id+':'+data.displayID]" capitalize="u_fln_dcc">
```

Inspect element For SearchButton

```
<button type="submit" id="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-binding" data-toggle="tooltip" ng-click="searchController.performSearch()" ng-disabled="searchController.callInProgress || searchController.searchForm.u_edi_claim.$invalid" title="Click this button to perform the search.">
```

---

```
    Sub macro()
    Dim a As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim Ist As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim i As IHTMLElement
    IE.Visible = True
    a = "https://doc30-ui.uhg.com/doc30-ui/search"
    IE.navigate a
    
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:3")
    
    Dim DOC  As New HTMLDocument
    Set DOC = IE.document
    Set Ist = DOC.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each i In Ist
        If i.ID = "u_edi_claim_key0" Then
           i.Focus
           i.Select
           i.Value = 66827839
        End If
        DOC.getElementById("Search").Click
    Next
    MsgBox "done"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check for any event listeners?

Comment: Hi @QHarr I got my answer. I've posted .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub macro()
    Dim a As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim Ist As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim i As IHTMLElement
    IE.Visible = True
    a = "https://doc30-ui.uhg.com/doc30-ui/search"
    IE.navigate a
    
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:3")
    
    Dim DOC  As New HTMLDocument
    Set DOC = IE.document
    Set Ist = DOC.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each i In Ist
        If i.ID = "u_edi_claim_key0" Then
           i.Focus
           i.Select
           i.Value = 66827839
           Exit For
           Application.Sendkeys "~"
        End If
        
    Next
    Application.Sendkeys "~"
    MsgBox "done"
    End Sub
```

Comment: `With DOC.querySelector("[id='u_edi_claim_key0']")` ......`End With`  - instead of looping. You should try and avoid using SendKeys and see what less error prone methods trigger acceptance/recognition of the text entry. E.g. https://pastebin.com/Nbr8p2qM